# need help picking web application framework for R

Tags: r, web-applications

Greeting.

We are developing some R code for statistical analystics.

It was originally intended to be used with the Oracle Business Intelligent Suite as the representation layer, however, the management wants us to explore other framework to display those data, and asked us to come up with suggestions.

So far there are the candidates.

```
1. shiny from Rstudio
2. OpenCPU apps. opencpu.org 
3. rapache http://rapache.net/
```

We are an academic organization dealing with sensitive data, so security is a major concern. Also, our management does not have a big budget, so opensource or tools that come with a significant institutional/academic discount are preferred. So far I am inclined towards shiny but, it's relatively new so it might not as stable as the other two.

Any suggestions especially first hand experience will really be appreciated.

Comment: This question is probably off-topic for SO, but generally when you have a "which package" type question you should start with the relevant task view. See http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/WebTechnologies.html, which has a whole section on web frameworks.

Comment: I loved the question but it is opinion based and not really specifically about coding, thus I voted to close as not a good fir for SO as is.

Comment: My advice would be to set up 2 servers. One holding the webapplication written in whatever language you like and another webserver holding the R code using either OpenCPU or rApache. Only allow the webapplication to connect to the OpenCPU/rApache server and no-one else.